# How can I print a multiline string in the same place multiple times?

Tags: ruby, special-characters

I am using Ruby.

I have a string with multiple lines. I want to print that multiple-lines-string in the same place multiple times.

The reason I want to do that is because the string represents information that is going to be updated several times.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Add an example of expected input and expected output, can't say i can understand what you're looking for here.

Comment: @Mauricio: Check Nash's answer. That is the behaviour I want to achieve. I was hoping to be able to use '\r' which can do what I want for a single line and it is much more cleaner. Add a new answer if you can propose a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option:

```
3.times do |i|
  print str = "string#{i}\nstring#{i}\nstring#{i}\n"
  sleep 1 # just for test
  system('clear')
end
```

Comment: I accept your answer since it the most simple and will work in any context.

Comment: Will 'clear' "work in any context" as you promise?  I am not convinced.  On Windows, the system call (at least it used to be) would be 'cls'.

Answer (score 1):

This will work however in Terminal.app on Mac OS X Lion the 1 character of each line is cleared on exit. I think this is a bug of Terminal.app.

```
CR = "\r"
CLEAR = "\e[0J"
RESET = CR + CLEAR

lines_count = 3

3.times do |i|
  puts "First line #{i}"
  puts "Second line #{i}"
  puts "Third line #{i}"
  sleep(1)
  $stdout.flush

  lines_count.times do
    print "\e[1F"
    print "\e[1K"
  end
end
print "\e[#{lines_count}E"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use uses [curses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/curses/rdoc/index.html) to handle your output but that would probably be overkill for something simple like this.

The usual way is to print out a bunch of backspaces to reposition the output cursor at the beginning of your last string; be aware that `"\b"` doesn't necessarily overwrite anything so you'll have to overwrite the end with spaces to be safe. Something like this:

```
messages = [
    'Professionally simplify seamless systems with prospective benefits.',
    'Dramatically cultivate worldwide testing procedures for robust potentialities.',
    'Intrinsicly provide access to future-proof testing procedures after superior supply chains.',
    'Globally matrix multidisciplinary outsourcing vis-a-vis distributed paradigms.',
    'Compellingly fashion visionary content via functionalized web services.',
    'Phosfluorescently e-enable e-markets rather than internal or "organic" sources.'
]
reposition    = ''
clear_the_end = ''
(0 ... messages.length).each do |i|
    if(i > 0)
        clear_the_end = ' ' * [0, messages[i - 1].length - messages[i].length].max
    end
    $stdout.syswrite(reposition + messages[i] + clear_the_end)
    reposition = "\b" * (messages[i].length + clear_the_end.length)
    sleep 1
end
puts
```

You'll want to use [`syswrite`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000904) to avoid buffering and the usual `"\n"` that [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000893) appends. This sort of thing should work in any terminal that you're likely to come across.

You could also use a carriage return (`"\r"`) instead of a bunch of backspaces:

```
# `reposition = "\b" * (messages[i].length + clear_the_end.length)` becomes
resposition = "\r"
```

But you'll still need all the `clear_the_end` fiddling to make sure you overwrite all of the last line.